# Espaçamentos Cross-browser em Mail Marketing

Tags: html, css, html5, envio-de-email

Estou desenvolvendo uma peça de E-mail Marketing e estou tendo problemas com espaçamentos de table, tr e td nos navegadores IE e com o Outlook e Outlook WebmailApp

Os navegadores renderizam corretamente, se você notar os cantos arredondas de cima dos boxes, que são inseridos como imagem ficam com um espaço em branco entre eles e a próxima Table, eu gostaria que esse espaços saíssem, como acontece no gmail por exemplo.

Outro problema é que não consigo aplicar cor de fundo no Hotmail, simplesmente não vai..

Estou testando pelo: http://putsmail.com/

Segue o código que estou usando, se alguém souber de algo que estou fazendo errado ou que possa me ajudar, qualquer ajuda seria bem vinda, Obrigado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#007088" style="margin:0px; background-color:#007088; width:100%;"  >


<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="border:0px solid #b59ec3;">
    <tr>
        <td>


    <table width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#e8e7e7"><tr><td>

       <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border:0px solid #333;">
       <tr>
            <td width="180" height="20" align="left" >
                            <font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">
                            <a href="#" style="font-size:9px; color:#bbbbbb; text-decoration:none;" border="0">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </a>
                            </font>
            </td>
            <td width="450"  align="right" >
                            <font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" style="font-size:8.5px; color:#bbbbbb;"> Lorem Lorem Lorem
                            <a href="#" style="font-size:9px; color:#999999; text-decoration:none;" border="0">Lorem Lorem</a></font>
                              <font face="Verdana" style="font-size:8.5px; color:#bbbbbb;">| Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
                            <a href="#" style="font-size:9px; color:#999999; text-decoration:none;" border="0">Lorem Lorem</a></font>
            </td>
        </tr>

       </table>

       </td></tr></table>



        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" >
        <tr><td width="143">
           <!--Logo-->
            <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="Lorem"  width="143" height="53" border="0" style="display:block; background-color:#0F00f0;" title="Lorem" /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
           <!--Menu-->
            <table width="487" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:block">
              <tr bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                <td width="65" height="36" valign="middle" style=" background-color:#bd0000;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="65" height="24" border="0" style="display:block" /></a></td>
                <td width="120" height="36" valign="middle" style=" background-color:#bd0000;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="122" height="24" border="0" style="display:block" /></a></td>
                <td width="95" height="36" valign="middle" style=" background-color:#bd0000;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="95" height="24" border="0" style="display:block" /></a></td>
                <td width="118" height="36" valign="middle" style=" background-color:#bd0000;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="118" height="24" border="0" style="display:block" /></a></td>
                <td width="87" height="36" valign="middle" style=" background-color:#bd0000;"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="87" height="24" border="0" style="display:block" /></a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
                </tr>
       </table>

    </td></tr>
    </table>


<table width="598" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#d5eaed">
      <tr>
        <td width="184" height="107" align="left"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="184" height="107" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td width="207" height="107" align="center"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="207" height="107" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td width="209" height="107" align="right"><img src="" alt="Lorem" title="Lorem" width="209" height="107"  /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>


 <!-- TABELA lado 1-->


<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#d5eaed">

    <tr>
        <td height="5" width="590"  bgcolor="#d5eaed" align="center"><img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-cima-grande_zps0c6011f9.jpg" width="580" height="15" style=" display:table;" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><TABLE width="580" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="#d5eaed">

    <TR>

        <td width="180" height="200"><img src="" width="180" height="180" /></td>

        <TD width="300"><font style="font-size:16px" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#666666">
                            <strong><a href="" target="_blank" style="color:#454545;text-decoration:none">
                            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#666666" style="font-size:16px; line-height:25px;">
                            <strong>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</strong>
                            </font><br />
                            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#999999" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 20px; font-weight:normal;">
                            Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
                            </font>
                            </a></strong>
                            </font><br />
                            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#999999" style="width:100%; font-size:12px; ">
                            <font style="font-size:12px;">Lorem Lorem
                            <font style="font-size:12px; color:#dc002e;">R$</font>
                            </font>
                            <font style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
                            XX<sup style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">,XX</sup>
                            </font></font><br />
                        <table align="center" height="60" ><tr><td>
                        <img src="" alt="Raia Arrasa!" title="Raia Arrasa!" width="53" height="27"  />
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ed8c00" style="font-size:12px;"> 
                        Lorem ipsum
                        <font style="font-size:16px; "><strong>X<sup style="font-size:10px;">,XX</sup> </strong></font>
                        Lorem ipsum</font>
                        </td></tr></table>

                       <table align="center" height="60" width="290"><tr><td>
                        <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img src="" alt="comprar" title="comprar" width="263" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;" /></a>
                        </td></tr></table>

         </TD> 
         <td width="90">
             <table align="center" border="0" width="90">
                 <tr >
                     <td border="0">
                         <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;"  border="0">
                            <img src="" width="82" height="52" border="0"/>
                         </a>
                     </td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>
            <br />
            <table  align="center">
                 <tr >
                     <td style="border:0px solid #333;" align="center">
                         <img src="" width="6" height="52" style="float:left;" />
                         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#838383" style="font-size:8px; width:36px; height: 43px;padding-top: 7px; float:left;border-top:1px solid #e7e7e7; border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                         <font color="#1897a8" style="font-size:20px;">xxx </font>pontos</font>
                         <img src="" width="40" height="52"  />
                      </td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>

       </td>
   </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE width="580" bgcolor="#d3ecf0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="12"   >
    <TR><TD width="580"><img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-baixogrande_zpseed08f97.jpg" width="580" height="18" /></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</td></tr>

    <tr><td height="15" width="580"></td></tr>  

<tr><td style="border:10px solid #d6e9ee;" width="280" >
    <table width="280" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" left="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#d6e9ee"><img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-cima1_zps14860d1c.jpg" width="280" height="15" /></td>
    </tr>      

    <tr >
    <td align="center" width="280" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" ><font style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">
        <strong>
        <a href="" target="_blank" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none">
        Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum <br />
        <span style="font-weight:normal;font-size:14px; color:#999999;">Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</span>
        </a></strong></font></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="15"></td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td><table width="280"><tr>
                <td width="170"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" width="180" height="180" border="0" /></a></td>
                <td style="border:0px solid green;" width="115" align="center" >
                 <img src="" width="6" height="52" style="float:left;" />
                 <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#838383" style="font-size:8px; width:36px; height: 43px;padding-top: 7px; float:left;border-top:1px solid #e7e7e7; border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                 <font color="#1897a8" style="font-size:20px;">xxx </font>
                 </font>
                 <img src="" width="40" height="52" style="float:left;" />
                 <table><tr><td>&nbsp; </td></tr></table>
                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">
                 <img src="" width="82" height="52" border="0"/>
                 </a></td>
             </tr></table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>  
    <tr >
        <td width="280" align="center">
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#999999" style=" width:100%; font-size:13px; ">
        Ips um <strong>XX<sup style="font-size:8px;">,XX</sup></strong> por 
        <font style="font-size:12px;">Ipsum 
        <font style="font-size:12px; color:#dc002e;">R$</font>
        </font>
        <font style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
        XX<sup style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">,xx</sup>
        </font>
        </font>
        </td>           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
        <td width="275" align="center">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="comprar" title="comprar" width="263" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr><td width="280" bgcolor="#d6e9ee">
        <img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-baixo1_zpse6fe648e.jpg" width="280" height="15"  />    
        </td></tr>

</table>

<table width="280" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" left="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#d6e9ee"><img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-cima1_zps14860d1c.jpg" width="280" height="15" /></td>
    </tr>      

    <tr >
    <td align="center" width="280" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" >
        <font style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">
        <strong><a href="" target="_blank" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none">
        Lorem2 Ipsum2 Lorem2 Ipsum2 Ipsum2 <br />
        <span style="font-weight:normal;font-size:14px; color:#999999;">Lorem2 Ipsum2 Ipsum2 </span>
        </a></strong></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="15"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td><table width="280">
                <tr>
                <td width="170"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" width="180" height="180" border="0" /></a></td>
                <td width="105" align="center">
                 <img src="" width="6" height="52" style="float:left;" />
                 <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#838383" style="font-size:8px; width:36px; height: 43px;padding-top: 7px; float:left;border-top:1px solid #e7e7e7; border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                 <font color="#1897a8" style="font-size:20px;">xxx </font>
                 </font>
                 <img src="" width="40" height="52" style="float:left;" />
                 <table><tr><td>&nbsp; </td></tr></table>
                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">
                 <img src="" width="82" height="52" border="0"/>
                 </a></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>  

    <tr >
        <td width="280" align="center">
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#999999" style=" width:100%; font-size:13px; ">
        Lo rem<strong>XX<sup style="font-size:8px;">,xx</sup></strong> por 
        <font style="font-size:12px;">Ipsum
        <font style="font-size:12px; color:#dc002e;">Lo</font>
        </font>
        <font style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
        XX<sup style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#dc002e;" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">,xx</sup>
        </font>
        </font>
        </td>           
    </tr>

    <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>  

    <tr><td width="275" align="center"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="comprar" title="comprar" width="263" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;" /></a></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr><td width="280" bgcolor="#d6e9ee"><img src="http://i873.photobucket.com/albums/ab298/ndezena/mktRAIA/barra-baixo1_zpse6fe648e.jpg" width="280" height="15"  /></td></tr>    

</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Colei seu código na ferramenta e vi que faltou fechar um `<td>` na linha 55.

Eu ia falar pra você testar essas coisas, mas acho que você já tentou:

- colocar `style="display:block"` nas imagens.
- colocar a cor de fundo na `<td>` e a tabela dentro, para ver se pega.

Mas fazer email mkt é realmente chatinho. Geralmente eu exporto das slices do Photoshop/Fireworks mesmo, porque apesar do código ser sujo, é isso que os programas entendem :/

Comment: `style="display:block"` nas imagens é indispensável.